# read the XML type column using stored procedure

Tags: oracle

How to display parent tags and attributes from XML TYPE column using stored procedure?

Example: I have below data in XMLTYPE Column in one table:

```
<Employee>
  <Employee_information >    
  <Employee_content>
    <task>
      <Employee_stem>
        <Employee_stem_paragraph>fsdbnfjksdflsdj.</Employee_stem_paragraph>
        <Employee_stem_paragraph>dsfsdfsdfsdf</Employee_stem_paragraph>
      </Employee_stem>    
      <Employee_response>
        <Employee_response_choices>    
          <Employee_choice_list>
            <Employee_block_choice numeric_identifier="1">              
            <Employee_choice_paragraph>sdfsdfsdfsdf</Employee_choice_paragraph>
            </Employee_block_choice>    
          </Employee_choice_list>   
       </Employee_response_choices>    
</Employee>
```

Output: display all the parent tags and attributes in it.

Output example:

> Employee,Employee_information,Employee_content,Employee_stem,Employee_stem_paragraph,Employee_response,Employee_response_choices,Employee_choice_list,Employee_block_choice,
>       numeric_identifier,Employee_choice_paragraph.

Comment: Review the data. You are missing some closing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you have to fix you xml. All tag have to be closed. 
1-st select `//*/name(.)` -  extract only element's name.
2-en select `'//*/name(@*)` -extract only attributes' name.

```
select *
  from xmltable('//*/name(.)'
                passing xmltype('<Employee>
  <Employee_information>
  <Employee_content>
    <task>
      <Employee_stem>
        <Employee_stem_paragraph>fsdbnfjksdflsdj.</Employee_stem_paragraph>
        <Employee_stem_paragraph>dsfsdfsdfsdf</Employee_stem_paragraph>
      </Employee_stem>    
      <Employee_response>
        <Employee_response_choices>    
          <Employee_choice_list>
            <Employee_block_choice numeric_identifier="1">              
            <Employee_choice_paragraph>sdfsdfsdfsdf</Employee_choice_paragraph>
            </Employee_block_choice>    
          </Employee_choice_list>   
       </Employee_response_choices>    
            </Employee_response>
            </task>
        </Employee_content>
      </Employee_information>    
</Employee>') columns name varchar2(200) path '.' )
union all 
select *
  from xmltable('//*/name(@*)'
                passing xmltype('<Employee>
  <Employee_information>
  <Employee_content>
    <task>
      <Employee_stem>
        <Employee_stem_paragraph>fsdbnfjksdflsdj.</Employee_stem_paragraph>
        <Employee_stem_paragraph>dsfsdfsdfsdf</Employee_stem_paragraph>
      </Employee_stem>    
      <Employee_response>
        <Employee_response_choices>    
          <Employee_choice_list>
            <Employee_block_choice numeric_identifier="1">              
            <Employee_choice_paragraph>sdfsdfsdfsdf</Employee_choice_paragraph>
            </Employee_block_choice>    
          </Employee_choice_list>   
       </Employee_response_choices>    
            </Employee_response>
            </task>
        </Employee_content>
      </Employee_information>    
</Employee>') columns name varchar2(200) path '.' )
```

Comment: Hi, The bottom part of sql does not work for the BELOW xml...

<formatted_text text_decoration="underline" font_style="italic" font_weight="bold">HI, I AM TEXT </formatted_text> 

I want to list all attribute names and its values in separate rows

for e.g. 
text_decoration   underline
fonst_style   italic
font_weight   bold

Comment: Thank you..the logic helped.. and i am able to get the attributes also from parent tag with values. Thank you..